# How to run a Github Action when a pull requestion is merged to master?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, github-actions, continuous-delivery

I am new to Github actions and I have searched all over to answer my question. I have an action setup to run on all push events but apparently that does not count for merging pull requests. So I wanted to know how I can run an action when a pull request is merged.

Answer (score 0):

```
name: CI
on: push

jobs:
  test:
    name: test
    ... 

  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: [test] # will wait until test finished
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
    steps:
      ...
```

One way is to use [if condition](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions).

Comment: Does doing on push work for you? The pipeline I made did not run when the pr was merged to master as noted in the question.

Comment: It works on my end. If you want to specifically handle pull_request event, this might be worked: 
https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/pull-request-action-does-not-run-on-merge/m-p/32528/highlight/true#M1168

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below syntax colective or the one you want.
It will trigger the  pipeline on every direct push in the master branch and on every PR merged in the master branch.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
    types:
      - closed
```